# MongoDB Will too much authentication causes cpu usage high?

Tags: mongodb

We are encountering a high CPU kernel load on the mongod system. According to the monitoring tools, the DB instance does not have high OPS, which only is under 1000 operations per second, including all the read and write requests. But the system CPU load is about 10%, which is total strange, because the mongod would only consume user space CPU, not the system space.
I searched the mongod log files, in which there is a lot of authentication items and within 10min, there would be more than 150 thousands authentication log. I know it is too much, but I want to make sure whether it is the key root for the high cpu load.

Here is some info about the log, and the CPU load:
The pic below is the log output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnH5d.png)

And the below pic the CPU load:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6wVs.png)

The mongod doesn't have heavy operation load, so I don't think it is caused by the app operations. What I want to know is too much authentication would cause the CPU load increase, which is mainly resulted in system space load.
Thanks first.

Comment: Have you added any indexes?

Comment: I don't think it is caused by index missing. If there is an index needed not created, which would generate slow log appears in the log file. Am I mistake your point?

Comment: No, my point is, index would return results faster. Without index, the CPU will have to go through each and every doc to get the results.

Comment: What I am sure is that the high CPU system space load is not caused by missing indexes.

Comment: The image you attached does not show a high CPU usage anywhere. Its not even 20%

Comment: The high load is not referred to the percentage of the CPU, instead it should  not consume too much kernel time. After restart the application, the red line decreases, so the too-much authentication used this much kernel time. What I want to know is that, how the authentication consume system space time.